# Why I can't get an index from list filled with Ints?

Tags: python, list

So, it gives me

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'

```
length = int(input())
arrayOfStrings = input()
number= 0
arrayofnumbers = list(map(int, arrayOfStrings.split()))

minimum = arrayofnumbers[0]
for i in range(1, len(arrayofnumbers)):
     if minimum<arrayofnumbers[i]:
        number = arrayofnumbers[i].index(i) ErrorString
        minimum = arrayofnumbers[i]
     elif minimum==arrayofnumbers[i]&number<i :
        number = i-1
     i+=1
print(number)
```

Comment: What does you expect that line to do? `arrayofnumbers[i]` is an `int`.

Comment: `arrayofnumbers.index(i)`

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: `arrayofnumbers[i].index(i)`? `arrayofnumbers` is a list of integers, so `arrayofnumbers[i]` is one such integer. Integers don't have the `.index` method.

Comment: You need `and` instead of `&` if the `elif` as well. `&` is bitwise-and not logical-and

Comment: `i` _is_ the index. Also don't need to increment `i` in the `for` loop.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: i know that this code is full of other errors, but now i wanna inderstand why i can't det index from list. So strange language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors:

1. `elif minimum==arrayofnumbers[i]&number<i` you have to do an AND logic here, so use `and` instead of `&`.
2. `arrayofnumbers[i].index(i)` arrayofnumbers[i] is an integer, so you have to cast into a str before use "index" method
3. Why `i+=1`? For loop increment i by default in range
4. Use built-in `min()` method 'cause it's better if you want to find the minimum element of an array:

   `min(arrayofnumbers)`

Answer (score 1):

arrayofnumbers[i] is an integer, not a string or object. So, you can not index into integer value. instead you can modify error line to **number = arrayofnumbers.index(i)**, because list supports the indexing.